# Cannot start specific WebSphere Application Server

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

I am receiving an error when starting application server. I am getting this error only specific server, the other starting perfectly fine. We are using WebSphere 8.0.0.9 version. I have shared the log below. I am not familiar with WebSphere system so if you need anything else beside this log, I will try to share it.

[image]

Exception Log:

```
    class load: org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugTrace from: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_.jar
class load: org.osgi.framework.InvalidSyntaxException from: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:292)
        at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:311)
        at java.util.Random.nextLong(Random.java:252)
        at java.io.File.generateFile(File.java:1693)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile0(File.java:1736)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1814)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.AdaptorUtil.canWrite(AdaptorUtil.java:208)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.LocationManager.canWrite(LocationManager.java:276)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.LocationManager.buildLocation(LocationManager.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.LocationManager.initializeLocations(LocationManager.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:394)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:157)
class load: java/text/MessageFormat
class load: java/text/FieldPosition
class load: java/util/Date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1020621) for directions on adding the IBM JVM specific security service classes to theserver configuration, in particular the java.ext.dirs JVM property definition.  The technote is for the IBM i platform, and based on the file location of the native_stderr.log you pasted above, I believe you're on a Linux platform, but the technote should still apply.

Comment: I was able to fix this problem with the description on the link.
In Linux jre ext lib path something like below.
-Djava.ext.dirs=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ext

Comment: One thing I see in your status screenshot is that you have some error(s) on core, and then errors on core_preprod. I'm wondering what are the errors on each and are they related?

You have 2 errors showing up on Node01, I suspect they are related. From the log, I see it's throwing a NullPointerException loading java classes and there's an InvalidSyntaxException. I would look at the 2 jar files and look for syntax errors. If you are not experienced in Java, then please ask someone from your development team to take a look.